# Contact/s or Contact(s)

Tags: mobile-application, text

My mobile app has a screen which shows Emergency contacts for that user. Contacts can be 1 or more than 1. What is correct standard or practice to show screen title -  **Contact/s OR Contact(s)**.

Comment: Can you provide an image of your current version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gregg Reference Manual](http://www.mhhe.com/business/buscom/gregg/) recognises *plural endings in parentheses* as being the defacto way of showing conditional plurals.

i.e. Contact(s) rather than Contact/s.

However, in your case there seems to be no benefit to putting the plural ending in parentheses, so simply using **Contacts** would have the same effect and be more readable.

Comment: I always tend to have a 'count==1' test while rendering the page, so it'll say "1 Contact" or "2 Contacts", but I agree "n Contact(s)" is vastly better than "n Contact/s".

Comment: In addition, just the word "Contact" can be taken as a verb instead of a noun and seem like an action instead of a description.

Answer (score 0):

"Emergency Contact List" might be clearer and not need to be singular or plural, but kind of long.

I don't think there's anything wrong with a plural header and only one item. It's different from seeing "1 somethings" ...just my opinion